# Get real logged in user when impersonation is used

Tags: c#, impersonation

Here's a question that's hard to research... how would I obtain the name of the "real" user that is logged in, when impersonation is used? I'm aware that it's possible if I turned impersonation off and then back on, but that's difficult in my situation and am looking for something simpler.

I've tried the following, which all point to the ImpersonationUser:
`Environment.UserName`
`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`
`SystemInformation.Username`

Here is the code that impersonates the user (not sure how much it helps):

```
        if (LogonUser(userName, "ABDATA", pwd, LogonSessionType.Interactive, LogonProvider.Default, ref this._userToken))
        {
            if (DuplicateToken(this._userToken, SecurityImpersonationLevel.SecurityImpersonation, ref this._impersonationToken))
            {
                this._identity = new WindowsIdentity(this._impersonationToken, "Kerberos", WindowsAccountType.Normal, true);
                this._impersonationContext = this._identity.Impersonate();
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(this._identity);
            }
            else
            {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
            }
        }
```

We basically want the permissions of this impersonation user so that it can access certain files, but want to be able to display the actual logged-in user's name for accountability purposes.

Looking for any solution really.. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you get real user name before the impersonation block and keep it assigned to a variable ?

Comment: That's the first thing I thought of, and where it gets difficult. Unfortunately, there's a wall between the methods I can pass that parameter through, and the method that needs it. Something called Type.InvokeMember. Basically this is a method that executes a "transaction" (not a SQL transaction) and the transaction has steps. I would need to take the variable to one of these steps, but it seems I can't. When I go to definition, it takes me to metadata.

Comment: ASP.NET application or a desktop application?

Comment: @DonalLafferty It's a desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

Cache the user details in a [ThreadStatic field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx)?